# Transferring Files via the Google Cloud SDK shell?

Tags: cloud, gcloud, file-transfer, scp

I have create an instance (vm) from the google cloud console. Connecting with the command `gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE]` works fine. 
I can exit from the instance shell, and return to Google Cloud SDK Shell. 
Afterwards in the Google Cloud SDK shell i am running the command `glcoud compute scp [ABS_FILE_PATH] [INSTANCE]`

The file upload succeeds,

```
aloe_fractal.jpg          | 99 kB |  99.1 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

but when i open up the instance shell and navigate to the uploaded file directory, there is no file?

```
gcloud compute scp C:\Users\abri\Desktop\__Main__\__recreational__\Art\aloe_fractal.jpg sugar:~\home\abri
```

No zone specified. Using zone [`us-central1-a`] for instance: [`sugar`].

```
aloe_fractal.jpg          | 99 kB |  99.1 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

```
abri@sugar:~/filefolder$ dir
abri@sugar:~/filefolder$
***no 'aloe_fractal.jpg' file'
```

What could be the possible causes, and has anyone else had this issue when using Google Cloud SDK shell, to make local to remote file transfers.

Comment: I'm confused. You appear to reference 3 different instances: Cloud Shell, your VM and a Windows machine. Is the VM running Windows?  If I understand correctly, you can `scp` the file from the Cloud Shell instance to the VM (correct?) but this doesn't work when you try to do it from a Windows machine to the VM? If so, I suspect (I've not tried) there's some issue using gcloud's `scp` command either from Windows or because you're using a Windows file system (`c:\Users\abri...`) reference.

Comment: The VM is running Linux. Yes correct i can scp the file from the Cloud Shell to the VM instance. But when i look into the directory of that instance, the files which were confirmed uploaded in the Cloud Shell, are not found in the VM instance path specified in the scp command.

Comment: I'll have a look at this tomorrow morning and report back. I've not tried Cloud Shell to|from insurances. You should use "/" as the separator for Linux and a dest of `[[instance]]:`should copy to your user's home directory. Don't forget to ensure `--project` is set too unless you're confident everything's in the same project.

Comment: Yes please try, and see what your experience can make of this. Also i ensured project was set via the command - gcloud config set project [PROJECT]

Comment: You can be explicit with `--zone=...` and `--project=...` on the command line too. This works for me. I uploaded a picture of my dog (`freddie.jpg`) to Cloud Shell. I created an instance `instance-1`. From Cloud Shell, I then `gcloud scp ./freddie.jpg instance-1: --zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT}`. This succeeded. I then `gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone=${ZONE} --project=${PROJECT}`. This takes me to my user's home directory (`/home/$(whoami)`) and the file was there with the correct size.

Comment: Where you write "I uploaded a picture of my dog `(freddie.jpg)` to Cloud Shell." . Could you please paste the full command that you executed to do this! (As i understand it, this was seperate command to the `gcloud compute scp [Destination_File] [Instance]`)

Comment: I'm going to describe this in an answer so as to be able to upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are redundantly specifying the home directory, first with `~` and finally with `/home/abri`. In linux, `~` represents the home directory so you can simply specify that as the destination folder like such:

```
gcloud compute scp C:\Users\abri\Desktop\__Main__\__recreational__\Art\aloe_fractal.jpg sugar:~/
```

Try running the above command and see if the file had been transferred successfully. When you ssh into the VM instance, you should be directly taken to the home directory where the file should be residing and if not, run `cd ~` to go there.

Comment: 'code'C:\Users\abri\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute scp C:\Users\abri\Desktop\__Main__\__recreational__\Art\aloe_fractal.jpg sugar:~/
No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-a] for instance: [sugar].'code'
<pscp: unable to open ~/: failure>
<ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [C:\Users\abri\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\pscp.exe] exited with return code [1].>

Comment: Can you run it with `--verbosity=debug` and provide the output? Also check if you do not already have a file identically named. If all else fail, try running it while prepending it with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to upload a file from your localhost to Cloud Shell.

1. Using the Cloud Shell UI

[image]

2. I learned today that there's a [`gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/cloud-shell/scp) command:

```sh
gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp \
  localhost:path/to/freddie.jpg \
  cloudshell: --project=${PROJECT}
```

The command differs slightly from standard `scp`. Using the wrapper `gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp`, you must specify source and destination machines and one must be `localhost:` and one must be `cloudshell:`.

You may need to enable the cloudshell service in `${PROJECT}`. If necessary, you will be prompted, or:

```sh
gcloud services enable cloudshell.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}
```